# Image slider jerks when I set height in %

Tags: css, reactjs

I have an image slider react app. the slider works fine if I set height of the image in px. it is important for me to set image height in %. However setting image height in % is causing the div below the slider to jerk. Please help me how to set image height in % without causing the lower div to jerk up and down. Note that setting image height in vh also solves jerking of lower div, but does not resize height of image when window width resizes. Setting image height in % resizes height of image proportional to window width resizing (that is what I want), but the lower div jerks up and down for a fraction of a second when clicking next/previous slide. Thank you in advance.

```
APP.js
------

import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import './App.css'
import ImageSlider from './ImageSlider'
import { sliderData } from './sliderData'
const App = () => {

  return (
    <AppContainer>
      <ImageSlider slides={sliderData} />
      <div className='app'>
        <p>
          How to use Text Editor
          First, select a text file from your computer, Google Drive, or GMail attachment.
          The file will be displayed in your browser where you can then make any changes or edits.
          After edits are made, press the "Save to Drive" button to save the edited file back to Google Drive.
          Download a copy of the file to your computer or device using the "Download" button.
          How Text Editor works
          Text Editor is a pure Javascript web app. All processing is done locally in your web browser and on your computer.
          This app will open a text file of your choice, letting you make changes and save back them to Google Drive or your computer.
          Text Editor can open all text files types including TXT, CSV, HTML, XML, CSS and JSON as well as code files such as C++, Java, and Python.
          Standard text editor features are supported including syntax highlighting, word wrap, themes, and keyboard shortcuts.
          Keyboard shortcuts are supported; press the "Keyboard" icon in the toolbar to display a list of all keyboard shortcuts.
        </p>
      </div>
    </AppContainer>
  )
}

export default App

const AppContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

ImageSlider.js
--------------

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './ImageSlider.css'
import ArrowBackIosIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowBackIos';
import ArrowForwardIosIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForwardIos';

const ImageSlider = ({ slides }) => {
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
    const length = slides?.length;

    console.log(slides)

    const nextSlide = () => {
        setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1);
    };

    const prevSlide = () => {
        setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1);
    };

    if (!Array.isArray(slides) || slides.length <= 0) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <div className='slider'>
        {slides?.map((slide, index) => (
            <div className={index === current ? 'slide active' : 'slide'} key={index}>
                {index === current && (
                    <img src={slide?.image} alt='travel image' className='image'/>
                )}
            </div>
            ))}
            {slides?.length > 1 &&
                <>
                    <ArrowBackIosIcon
                        className='left-arrow'
                        onClick={prevSlide}
                        style={{
                            fontSize: 35,
                            color: 'white',
                            backgroundColor: '#111',
                            padding: 12,
                            paddingLeft: 18,
                            paddingRight: 6,
                            borderRadius: 999,
                        }}
                    />
                    <ArrowForwardIosIcon
                        className='right-arrow'
                        onClick={nextSlide}
                        style={{
                            fontSize: 35,
                            color: 'white',
                            backgroundColor: '#111',
                            padding: 12,
                            alignContent: 'center',
                            borderRadius: 999,
                        }}
                    />
                </>
            }
        </div>
    );
};

export default ImageSlider;


sliderData.js
-------------

export const sliderData = [
    {
        id: 0,
        image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546768292-fb12f6c92568?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501446529957-6226bd447c46?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1489&q=80'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1483729558449-99ef09a8c325?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475189778702-5ec9941484ae?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503177119275-0aa32b3a9368?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80'
    }
];

app.css
-------

.app {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

ImageSlider.css
---------------

.slider {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .image {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
        aspect-ratio: 16/9;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }

    .right-arrow {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 1%;
        font-size: 3rem;
        color: #000;
        z-index: 10;
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
        opacity: 0.6;
    }

    .left-arrow {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 1%;
        font-size: 3rem;
        color: #000;
        z-index: 10;
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
        opacity: 0.6;
    }

    .slide {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 1.5s ease;
    }

    .slide.active {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 1.5s ease;
        transform: scale(1.05);
}


The problem occurs when I change height: 600px; to for example height: 60%; 

.image {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
        aspect-ratio: 16/9;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
```

Comment: try setting in vh

Comment: @NabeelKhan setting in vh solves jerking like px. But vh does not suit my purpose. I want the image to resize dynamically when resizing the window.

Comment: that is what vh do :) it resizes based on size of window

Comment: @NabeelKhan I tried setting height in vh, but image height is not resizing when i resize the width of the window. And that is what I want, image height should resize when i resize width of the window.

Comment: try giving min-height as vh and normal height as % ?